# Search start of the word using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

How to write regular expression where we can find all words which are started by specified string. For ex-

```
a = "asasasa sasDRasas dr.klklkl DR.klklklkl Dr klklklkklkl"
```

Here I want to fetch all words which are starting by `dr` using ignorecase. I tried but all functions results where `dr` is found in word not start of the word.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\b` to find word boundaries, and the `re.IGNORECASE` flag to search case-insensitively.

```
import re

a = "asasasa sasDRasas dr.klklkl DR.klklklkl Dr klklklkklkl"
for match in re.finditer(r'\bdr', a, re.IGNORECASE):
    print 'Found match: "{0}" at position {1}'.format(match.group(0), match.start())
```

This will output:

```
Found match: "dr" at position 18
Found match: "DR" at position 28
Found match: "Dr" at position 40
```

Here, the pattern `\bdr` matches *dr*, but only if it is found at the start of a word.  This will also yield matches for strings like *driving*.  If you only want to find *dr* as unique word, use `\bdr\b`.

I use [`re.finditer()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer) to scan through the search string and yield every match for *dr* in a loop.  The `re.IGNORECASE` flag causes `dr` to also match `DR`, `Dr` and `dR`.

Answer (score 1):

[@Ferdinand Beyer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746157/search-start-of-the-word-usiing-regular-expression-in-python/6746243#6746243) shows how to do it by regex. But you can easily achieve that with string functions:

```
>>> a
'asasasa sasDRasas dr.klklkl DR.klklklkl Dr klklklkklkl'
>>> cleaned = "".join(" " if i in string.punctuation else i for i in a)
>>> cleaned
'asasasa sasDRasas dr klklkl DR klklklkl Dr klklklkklkl'
>>> [word for word in cleaned.split() if word.lower().startswith("dr")]
['dr', 'DR', 'Dr']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> string_to_search_in
'this a a dr.seuse dr.brown dr. oz dr noone'
>>> re.compile('\b*?dr.?\s*?\w+', re.IGNORECASE).findall(string_to_search_in)
['dr.seuse', 'dr.brown', 'dr. oz', 'dr noone']
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution.

The expression will search and return the **exact** and **starting with** words from a string matched with a *string variable*.

```
import re

txt = "this a a dr.seuse dr.brown dr. oz dr noone"
suggtxt= "dr."
w_regex = r"\b"+re.escape(suggtxt)+r"+\S*"
x = re.findall(w_regex, txt,  re.IGNORECASE)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
['dr.seuse', 'dr.brown', 'dr.']
```